# 2007(?) iMac kernel panic, Apple hardware test detected no errors. Help troubleshooting verbose mode traceback

Tags: hard-drive, boot, mac, kernel, kernel-panic

I recently inherited an 2007 (I believe) iMac from my parents. They stored it in the basement ever since 2010 after the computer refused to boot. I want to recover the old files for them and then keep this computer as a spare for myself.

The computer immediately displays the kernel panic screen after trying to boot. So far I have:

- Tried booting in safe mode (failed)
- Tried booting in single-user mode (failed)
- Reset PRAM/NVRAM (didn't fix issue)
- Run Apple hardware test (found no errors)
- Booted with verbose mode (see image below)

[image]

I'm at the end of my knowledge on how to proceed. I think that this must be either a software or hard drive issue. Is there any hope for this computer? I know I can use target mode to recover the files (or just take the hard drive out) but I'd like to get this running as is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to boot into Recovery mode for disk repair process?

Data recovery from a non-booting Mac isn't a straightforward process as from a working Mac. I am sharing a few options for you.

1. You can try recovering data from this Mac using target disk mode wherein, you connect a non-booting Mac to a working Mac with a firewire or Thunderbolt cable. Once the connection is made and booted successfully you can access Macintosh HD of your iMac and retrieve files. However, there could be certain challenges like iMac's Macintosh HD not mounting or showing up.
2. If target disk mode is not possible then look for a data recovery software that supports non-bootable recovery.
3. Alternatively, try to put your iMac's drive into an external case.

Comment: I tried the target mode, but the iMacs HDD was not detected by my MacBook. Sounds like the best option is data recovery or just removing it and hooking it directly to my MacBook. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One thing, was your iMac HDD showing up in the Disk Utility when you connect via target disk mode?